# ruby on rails x charset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, character-encoding

i'm having problem to deal with charset in ruby on rails app, specificially in my templates. Code that comes from my database, works fine, but codes like ç ~ that are located in my views are not working. I added the following codes to my code

I added a function like that, but that still not working i have ç ~ codes in my application.rhtml that are not working.

```
before_filter :configure_charsets 
 # Configuring charset to UTF-8 def configure_charsets    
 headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"     
end
```

I added as well meta http-equiv html to utf-8 and a .htaccess parameter AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

That's still not working, any other tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this piece of code in your config (`environment.rb`)

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.action_controller.default_charset = "iso-8859-1"
end
```

This will do it.

Also, remove the default charset line if any in `layouts/application.html`

Comment: :-) Thanks swanand for the edit. I was not sure abt how to format in Stackoverflow. Tx for doing it !

Answer (score 2):

Is the text editor you're using to put the special characters into the file (either source or views) treating those characters as UTF-8? For example, if you're using TextMate, you can deliberately save a file as UTF-8. If for some reason you used a different encoding earlier (a default, perhaps), those UTF-8 characters might be getting transcoded at the code editing stage, so even if the rendering process is using UTF-8 throughout, it'll still not work.

Further, if you're using something from a shell, like vi, or whatever, is your terminal set up to accept UTF-8 as default? If you had it set to ISO-8859-1 or whatever, you'd get the same issue.

Comment: i doubled check it. I saved the file again as utf-8 encoding in my programmer notedpad but i'm still having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `application.rhtml` file written in the correct character set? Make sure it's UTF-8, and not ISO-8859-1.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: That doesn't mean it's written in UTF-8. It just means it's telling the browser that it's in UTF-8. You have to tell your text editor to save using the UTF-8 character set.

Answer (score 0):

So if the contents of your file are UTF-8, and the output is being interpreted as UTF-8, something in between is changing the data. Can give give us the the hex interpretation of the input bytes (anything non-ASCII will be at least two bytes in UTF-8) for one of your special characters, and the hex interpretation of the output byte or bytes? Perhaps we can figure out what the change is, and work back from there.